# Can I access "time of last login to Facebook" of a Facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to develop a Facebook app.But I couldn't find anything in graph API about "last login time" that I can access through a Facebook app with some permissions.

Can I access it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no API that returns the session information of your app's users or their friends

Comment: you saved a lot of time for me. Thanks a lot.